# Estimating probability of $\|Z_1\|^2-\|Z_2\|^2$ in a bivariate normal population

Tags: probability, statistics, normal-distribution, chi-squared

Suppose $(Z_1,Z_2)\sim N_2(\mu,0; 2,2; \frac{1}{2})$, i.e., a bivariate normal distribution with mean vector $(\mu,0)$ with each component having variance $2$ and covariance between the variables being $1$. Suppose $\{(Z_{1i},Z_{2i})\}_{i=1}^d$ is an independent and identically distributed sample on $(Z_1,Z_2)$. I am interested in finding a tight upper bound for the probability,
$$P\{\sum_{i=1}^d(Z_{1i}^2-Z_{2i}^2)\leq 0\}.$$

Intuitively, $\sum_{i=1}^d Z_{1i}^2$ is a noncentral chi-square distribution with noncentrality parameter $d\mu^2$ and $\sum_{i=1}^dZ_{2i}^2$ is a central chi-square distribution. Hence $\sum_{i=1}^d(Z_{1i}^2-Z_{2i}^2)$ is more likely to take positive values than negative values. It should be less than $\frac{1}{2}$. But by what amount? Can an upper bound be established like,
$$P\{\sum_{i=1}^d(Z_{1i}^2-Z_{2i}^2)\leq 0\} \leq \frac{1}{2}-f(\mu),$$
for some function $f$ ?

Any help or directions will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

By properties of multivariate normal RV's,
\begin{align*}
\begin{pmatrix}
X_i \\ Y_i
\end{pmatrix} \overset{\text{def}}{=}\begin{pmatrix}
Z_{1i} - Z_{2i} \\ Z_{1i} + Z_{2i}
\end{pmatrix} \sim N\left(\begin{pmatrix}
0 \\ 0
\end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix}
2 & 0 \\ 0 & 6
\end{pmatrix} \right)
\end{align*}
and so $Z_{1i}^2 - Z_{2i}^2 = X_iY_i$. Notice that $X_iY_i$ has symmetric densities about 0, and since [sum of symmetric RV's is symmetric](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/95002/the-sum-of-two-symmetric-random-variables-is-symmetric), we indeed have
\begin{align*}
P\left(\sum_{i=1}^{d}\{Z_{1i}^2 - Z_{2i}^2\} \le 0\right) = \frac{1}{2}
\end{align*}

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But did you assume that $\mu=0$? in that case the problem becomes trivial. Because in that situation the quantity is just a difference between two $\chi^2_d$ random variables. $\mu\not=0$ ensures that one is a non-central $\chi^2$ random variable and the other is a central $\chi^2$ random variable. Thus larger the $\mu$ is smaller will be the probability.  But your way is quite intuitive. I have tried this myself and found that this probability can be written as $E\left\{\Phi(-\frac{\mu\sum_{i=1}^d X_i}{\sqrt{6\sum_{i=1}^d X_i^2}})\right\}$, as in our notation.

Comment: Notice that for $\mu=0$ the probability is 0.5. As you have given. But for $\mu\not=0$ this quantity is quite intractable. Will you please give any suggestion about how to deal with it?